# How can I host static HTML on Azure and make it available only to authenticated users of my organization?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-active-directory

Our CI builds in Azure DevOps generate some static HTML reports such as Doxygen output. I would like to serve this to users of my organization as a website and prevent others from seeing it. The list of users exists in Azure Active Directory.

I have tried using a static website on Blob storage, but have not found a way to authenticate the users.

I'd like the output of the CI build to be added as a subfolder to the already existing builds like this:

```
.
├── build-1
│   ├── image.png
│   ├── index.html
│   └── site.css
├── build-2
│   ├── image.png
│   ├── index.html
│   └── site.css
└── latest -> build-2
```

It would also be nice to have the CI build maintain symbolic link to the newest build as shown above. However, if this would mean choosing a more complex solution, then I'll drop this requirement.

What is the simplest way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Azure Static Web Apps`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/overview) to host your application. These applications can be protected by Azure AD authentication/authorization.

Please see Microsoft's documentation on how to protect your web applications hosted in Azure Static Web Apps - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-authorization.

Comment: Could you add a bit of guidance for how to connect my Azure Static Web App to the existing Azure AD tenant and configure it to allow only users of a given group to access the site? Does this count as a custom Azure Active Directory provider registration? Do I use the method explained here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/authentication-custom?tabs=aad#configuration ? And if so, how do I set this up in Active Directory and create the client settings mentioned in that JSON snippet?

Comment: Unfortunately I am not too familiar with this service to provide answers to your questions.